# Error message when starting up Eclipse on MBP OS X10.7 and no Intel option in Extras

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Emulator won't work.

I receive this on Eclipse start-up:

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml, reason: File not found

And I cannot see Intel x86 option in my SDK, no matter if I force etc. I have downloaded the Intel x86 from the Intel website, but computer doesn't see it. Have downloaded HAXM, but it doesn't see Intel either.

Have trashed and re-istalled Eclipse about 5 times, same every time.

I am not on Windows.

When I try to open emulator I receive the following error [date, time - SDK Manager] Error: null

Anybody? I have been on forums all day to no avail.

Comment: can you specify total error message..

Comment: Hello;-)This is the entire error message I rcv:"Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml, reason: File not found" and then it finishes loading, everything is ok until I try to start an emulator, and then I realized that there is no 'Intel x86' option and so the emulator does not work. That is when I rcv the "SDK Manager] Error: null" message

Comment: In SDk Manger try to install package with latest one..

Comment: I have installed 18 and 19, but none of the packages I get include the "Intel x86 Atom System Image"

Answer (score 0):

Try it once it my Solve your problem

Open SDK Manager click tools in the top menu -> options and turn on "force h ttps://...sources"

and even this

try setting proxy in Eclipse->Android SDK Manager->Tools->Options-->force http

and

setting up the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME over Control Panel.

Start -> Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> New

Variable Name: ANDROID_SDK_HOME 
Variable Value: (the path is be your desired location of .android folder, excluding the last slash) For Example:
C:\Users\myUsername

Comment: Yes, I have tried this many times, but it will still never bring me the Intel x86 Atom System Image that I need

Comment: Under Android SDK Manager I have only two options under Tools, one is Manage AVDs and the other is Manage add-ons - I do not have an 'options'

Comment: on click on the Tools you will see drop-down menu in that options

Comment: Yes when I force I get this message: "Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml, reason: File not found
Done loading packages."

Comment: I tried and though it did download much more, still no Intel x86! I can't believe it, I thought we were so close;-) I get this message in the Eclipse Console: [2013-12-13 23:03:31 - SDK Manager] Error: null

Comment: I don't know what that means, and also I have a warning here that I can't move this to chat - my email is raveonstudio@gmail.com if you can contact me there?

Comment: I think this advice is far beyond what I can do - thank you so much for your time Maneti, I am not sure this Eclipse etc will work on my machine..

Comment: SOLVED!! I tried installing in my old 2009 MBP and it worked no problem, so I guess there is a bug in the newer 2011 MBP.